# How to trigger event every time text ctrl input complete?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a text ctrl defined as:

```
self.item= wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "",style=wx.TE_LEFT)
```

The user enter number in there.
I want that when he finished (say the focus was changed somewhere else) an event will be triggered.

What event can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind this event:

```
self.item.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnLoseFocus)
```

then catch the event with:

```
def OnLoseFocus(self,event):
    do actions...
    event.Skip()
```